# Android AdMob -onReceivedAd hit, but no ad displayed

Tags: android, admob

I've got my AdMob code implemented into my XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="30dp"
                     android:layout_height="30dp"
                     ads:adUnitId="???????"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In my onCreate method of my activity:

```
    // load ads
    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    //request.setTesting(true);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {     
        public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }           
        public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }           
        public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    adView.loadAd(request);
```

I can put a break point in the onReceivedAd listener and always stop in there when I run my app; however, nothing displays. My AdMob page shows requests happening as well. I've tried in and out of test mode (see the commented out line above) with the same results.

Also, lest anyone ask, my ads:adUnitId="????" is set to the `Publisher ID` found next to my app on the AdMob website.

Anyone got suggestions on how to debug this from here?

Comment: Why don't you put some code (and a break point on it) inside `public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1)` of the `AdListener` and see whether there's an error receiving the ad?

Comment: @Aleks - I had a line of code in each of the listener methods before (just int i=0; i++). The only breakpoint that ever hit was onReceivedAd - the other 3 were always skipped.

Comment: @mibollma - you are right man, I hadn't noticed that I put the ad within my tab host. I made a LinearLayout on top, then moved the adview and the tab host into that and it works. By all means, add an answer so you can get credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `TabWidget` and `FrameLayout` and try again just for testing.

I think `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on `FrameLayout` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Layout height should be 50dp (or more) to display ad. Ad is not getting enough space to display. Check logger.

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

and width should be wrap_content